# How to prevent docker-compose building the same image multiple times?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` specifies multiple images. Two of these images are built using the same local `Dockerfile`. They share the same image name but each has a different command.

During development, I frequently use `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild the images. The trouble is that docker builds the same `myimage` twice - taking longer than necessary.

Is there a way to express that the image only needs to be built once?

```
version: '2'
services:

  abc:
    image: myimage
    command: abc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  xyz:
    image: myimage
    command: xyz
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Unless you put the CMD directive at the top of the Dockerfiles, build caching should mean that the second run takes only a few seconds.  Just how much time does the second run take?

Comment: Both builds take around 10 seconds depending on the machine

Comment: Maybe build outside of compose? `docker build -t myimage . && docker-compose up`

Answer (score 90):

Per [the docker-compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for build, specify `build:` and `image:` for the first service, and then only `image:` for subsequent services.

Here's a modified version of your example that only builds the image once (for abc service) and reuses that image for xyz service.

```
version: '2'
services:

  abc:
    image: myimage
    command: abc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  xyz:
    image: myimage
    command: xyz
```

Comment: Is this (still?) the best way of doing this? It's pretty ugly, and definitely error prone if you're regularly adding and removing instances of this image, having to always make sure 1 of the instances contain build instructions.

Comment: After rereading the documentation linked in the answer, this still appears to be the best way to minimize `docker-compose up --build` time.

Comment: don't forget to add `depends_on: [abc]` in xyz service

Comment: Using this approach, `docker-compose pull` now tries to pull "myimage" from Docker Hub... but it's obviously not there. Otherwise, this approach saves a minute or more from my build times.

Comment: Ok, but in that case, I can not build a container for `xyz` without running first `docker-compose build abc`. I meam, the image `myimage` won't get build if I only run `docker-compose up xyz`, it will error.
Supposing I don't want to add `depends_on: abc` for the service `xyz`, because I don't care if the other service is started or not. I just want it's image

Comment: to resolve `docker compose pull` issue described above one could decorate all "myimage" usages with `pull_policy: never` property. A bit chatty, but resolves the issue

Answer (score 16):

You can fake a build only service to build the image, and then use dependencies to that for the actual workers. That has the advantage that you don't have one of those services automatically start if you wanna start the others.

you need to add an image name to specify `build:` and `image:` for the build service, as well as make sure it terminates and never restarts automatically.
Then `image:` and `depends_on: first_service` for your services.

like so:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  _myimage_build:
    image: myimage
    command: ['echo', 'build completed']  # any linux command which directly terminates.
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  first_service:
    image: myimage
    depends_on:
    - _myimage_build
    command: abc
    
  second_service:
    image: myimage
    depends_on:
    - _myimage_build
    command: xyz
```

thanks to @amath for their answer.

Make sure to first build the `myimage` image (`_myimage_build`) first, before trying to use the others: `docker compose build _myimage_build`

Comment: I did exactly as you but getting "pull access denied for myimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

Comment: Make sure to first build the `myimage` first, before trying to use the others: `docker compose build _myimage_build`

Answer (score 5):

To make @amath good answer a bit clearer

you need to add an image name to specify `build:` and `image:` for the first service, and then `image:` and `depends_on: first_service` for subsequent services.

like so:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:

  first_service:
    image: myimage
    command: abc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  second_service:
    image: myimage
    command: xyz
    depends_on:
    - first_service
```

thanks to @DrSensor for the comment

Comment: I did exactly as you but getting "pull access denied for myimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

Comment: It seems like your issue is related to login into your private docker, take a look at this
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/
or search for <your private docker name> docker login

Answer (score 3):

i run into similar issue.

I have two services based on the same image, just diff. configs.
The solution from @[luckydonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3423324/luckydonald) works for me, but not in the case, you just want to start the project by

```
docker compose up -d
```

There you will get the error for one of the services, that the image is not exists, while the first one will build.
'depends_on' Flag is only "run"-dependency, not build.

So to avoid building the image twice and get it running with first run of docker compose up, you can use "extend" in your services.

So basically we copy&paste answer of luckydonald and improve it a bit:

```
services:
  _myimage_build:
    image: myimage
    command: ['echo', 'build completed']  # any linux command which directly terminates.
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  first_service:
    image: myimage
    #here's the magic
    extends:
      service: _myimage_build
    command: abc

  second_service:
    image: myimage
    #here's the magic
    extends:
      service: _myimage_build
    command: xyz
```

it would be also possible to throw the first build job away, and do it in the first service, and the second one would extend the first... but as soon you have configuration like 'ports', extended service will !extend! it.

So example:

```
first_service:
  ....
  ports:
  - 80:80

second_service: 
  extends:
    service: first_service
  ports: 
  - 81:80
```

this will end with following error:

> port is already allocated

because first_service register 80:80
but the second one, takes the original "extended" ports and adds own one. So 80:80 AND 81:80

> For the multi-value options ports, expose, external_links, dns, dns_search, and tmpfs, Compose concatenates both sets of values

[See more of "extends" here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the behavior [changed](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7343#issuecomment-863008575), and now `docker compose` only builds once per `Dockerfile`.

This works now:

```yaml
services:
  abc:
    build: .
  xyz:
    build: .
```